# How to Download file Via terminal in google drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to download https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-NVzq-BWyV_YlZZWlZNbGVoems?usp=sharingthis file via terminal.

I use " wget https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-NVzq-BWyV_YlZZWlZNbGVoems?usp=sharing"command but

it doe not work.Kindly help me

I am using linux ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Its not working since the `wget` call is not authenticated. Also, indicate `alt=media` in the parameters.

If you check out [Download Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads)

> To download files, you make an authorized HTTP GET request to the file's resource URL and include the query parameter alt=media. For example:
>
> GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media
> Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHESVbXTUv5mHMo3RYfmS1YJonjzzdTOFZwvyOAUVhrs

Its an [old reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272770/wget-with-authentication), but I'm hoping this can help with you having an authenticated `wget` call.